# How to skip all callbacks except paper-trail when updating an ActiveRecord model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, paper-trail-gem

I have a model with paper-trail enabled. In one of my API routes, I have to run `the_model.update_columns ...` so that the model instance can be modified (and saved) without triggering all of the associated callbacks (these callbacks have a ton of side-effects which I don't want for this specific route).

However, **I still want this change to be recorded by paper-trail**. Is there a reasonable way I can achieve that?

Comment: it sounds like would be better off removing things from your callbacks unless you literally always want them to happen on every change. I can tell from your description that you want them on `X but not Y when Z is false`. just remove them and manually call the methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is simplistic and clunky, but it'd get done exactly what you want:

```
class ThisModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def update_me_no_callbacks(att_1, attr_2, attr_3, ...)
    self.update_columns(
      attr_1: attr_1,
      attr_2: attr_2,
      attr_3: attr_3,
      ...
    )

    # Do paper-trail code
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, that `# Do paper-trail code` is part of my problem. :-) I can't seem to find a documented way of manually triggering paper-trail.

Comment: Anyway, my current solution is to add a `, unless: :some_predicate?` after **all** of my callbacks. And then define that predicate to return `true` when I don't want the callbacks to run. It's a little cumbersome, but this way the paper-trail callbacks still get executed.